# Ballerina Oauth2 authenticated endpoint returning a 406

Tags: oauth-2.0, ballerina

I am trying to call a 3rd party service that uses Oauth2 Password Credentials to get an authentication token. Ballerina is returning the following messages.

```sh
2020-04-23 15:07:35,414 ERROR [ballerina/oauth2] - Received an invalid response with status-code: 406; and payload: {"fault":{"faultstring":"Raising fault. Fault name : RF.Raise-406-Exception","detail":{"errorcode":"steps.raisefault.RaiseFault"}}} 
2020-04-23 15:07:35,418 ERROR [ballerina/oauth2] - Failed to generate OAuth2 token. : error {ballerina/oauth2}Error message=Received an invalid response with status-code: 406; and payload: {"fault":{"faultstring":"Raising fault. Fault name : RF.Raise-406-Exception","detail":{"errorcode":"steps.raisefault.RaiseFault"}}} 
error {ballerina/http}AuthenticationFailed message=Failed to prepare request at bearer auth handler. cause=error {ballerina/auth}Error message=Failed to generate OAuth2 token. cause=error {ballerina/oauth2}Error message=Received an invalid response with status-code: 406; and payload: {"fault":{"faultstring":"Raising fault. Fault name : RF.Raise-406-Exception","detail":{"errorcode":"steps.raisefault.RaiseFault"}}}
```

It's the 406 code that is confusing me as I have set both the content type & accept headers to "application/json" which is what the service requires.
However, the second message says "Failed to generate OAuth2 token" so could it be the call to get the oauth token that is returning the 406? If so how do I set the accept header on the token service call?

Using Ballerina I have called the token endpoint and successfully got a token but if I try to call a service using a PasswordGrantConfig those are the errors I get. I've tried everything I can think of and have successfully got other services using ClientCredentialsGrantConfig to work.
Any help gratefully received.

The relevant code is below. The three sections below are parts of the code in 3 different .bal files.

```
// configure the Oauth2 Config
import ballerina/config;
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/oauth2;

public function getOauth2Handler() returns http:BearerAuthHandler {
    oauth2:PasswordGrantConfig passwordGrantConfig = {
        tokenUrl: config:getAsString("experian.authentication.tokenUrl"),
        username: config:getAsString("experian.authentication.username"),
        password: config:getAsString("experian.authentication.password"),
        clientId: config:getAsString("experian.authentication.clientId"),
        clientSecret: config:getAsString("experian.authentication.clientSecret"),
        credentialBearer: http:AUTH_HEADER_BEARER
    };
    oauth2:OutboundOAuth2Provider oauth2Provider = new (passwordGrantConfig);
    return new (oauth2Provider);
}

// Configure the API Client
http:ClientConfiguration delphiSelectClientConfig = {
    auth: {
        authHandler: experian:getOauth2Handler()
    }
};

experian:DelphiSelectClientConfig delphiSelectConfig = {
    serviceUrl: config:getAsString("experian.services.delphi-select.serviceUrl"),
    clientConfig: delphiSelectClientConfig
};

experian:DelphiSelectClient delphiSelectClient = new (delphiSelectConfig);

// Call the endpoint using the Oath2 configuration
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/io;

public type DelphiSelectClientConfig record {
    string serviceUrl;
    http:ClientConfiguration clientConfig;
};

//==============================
//============Client============
//==============================

public type DelphiSelectClient client object {
    public http:Client clientEp;
    public http:ClientConfiguration config;

    public function __init(DelphiSelectClientConfig config) {
        http:Client httpEp = new (config.serviceUrl, {auth: config.clientConfig.auth});
        self.clientEp = httpEp;
        self.config = config.clientConfig;
    }

    public remote function newApplication() returns @untainted json|error {
        io:println("In newApplication function");
        http:Request request = new;
        json requestBody = newApplicationBody; // get test data from json in another file
        request.setJsonPayload(requestBody);

        var response = check self.clientEp->post("/application", request);
        var payload = check response.getJsonPayload();
        return payload;
    }
};
```

I have also modified my test code to call the token EP and deliberately set `accept` to an unacceptable value, for example, `"text/csv"`. In this case I get the same error response. However setting `accept` to `"*/*"` does work. Final test; `accept` of `""` (empty) also fails so I suspect that the BearerAuthHandler is not setting any value for `accept`.

So can I force the BearerAuthHandler to set an `accept` of `"application/json"`?

Thanks.
See picture below.
[image: Picture showing requirement for content-type to be set to “application/JSON”]

Also, the example in the Oath2 spec you referenced shows a content-type value being set. Even a value of `“*/*”` would work but I suspect Ballerina leaves it blank.
I have raised the GitHub issue [Need to be able to set http header values for OutboundOAuth2Provider](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/22921)

Comment: Your request is not acceptable from the authorisation endpoint you are calling to. That is why you got 406. Can you please share your code without credentials?

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The problem can't be solved without seeing the code that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The main objective of `http:OutboundAuthHandler` objects are to prepare the `http:Request` with authentication information that needs to be authenticated with external endpoint you are calling to.

The `http:BearerAuthHandler` is responsible for adding `Authorization` header with the value of `Bearer <token>`. "token" is prepared with the provided information. So, there is no option to force `http:BearerAuthHandler` to set any header for the request.

But in this case, if the API successfully respond if there is `Accept` header with the value of `application/json`, you can simply add that header to the `http:Request` before calling the POST request as follow:

`request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");`

Comment: Thanks for your help but I tried that and it doesn't solve the problem. Your code changes the header value for the call to the 'business' endpoint. The problem is with the call to the AuthProvider endpoint that gets the authorization token needed to authorize the call to the 'business' endpoint. It is that AuthProvider endpoint that requires the specific Accept header. As far as I can tell there is no way to set the Accept value in the oauth2:PasswordGrantConfig or in any other way.

Comment: @Martin Yes. There is no way to set the `Accept` header in any of the OAuth2 grant types supported by Ballerina. According to the [OAuth2 RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.3), I couldn't find such behaviour/requirement. Please correct me if I am wrong. Just to clarify, can you please point me for the 3rd party token endpoint you are calling to or any doc related to that?

Comment: See picture added showing 3rd party token endpoint’s requirement for content-type value of “application/json”.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for sharing the image. According the RFC, access toke request set the content-type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and Ballerina also sends `Content-Type` header with that. But in your case, the experian API requests `application/json` as the value for `Content-Type`. Anyway, thanks for reporting the GitHub issue, we will discuss this further and update.

Comment: @idclakmal Thanks for the update. I have looked at the RFC & you are right, section 4.3.2 does state that `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` should be used for sending the password details. I will contact the 3rd party and let them know. However, I am not hopeful they will change & I suspect other 3rd Party's endpoint are also not compliant with the RFC so if Ballerina could default to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` but allow a developer to set other content-type values for non-compliant cases I think it would be useful. Kind regards, Martin.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the update. We will consider you requirement and will update the GitHub issue. In order to support custom authentication mechanisms like this, we have extended our authentication mechanism, with the support of adding custom auth providers. Therefore, for this requirement, you can implement a custom outbound auth provider and use the already available `http:BearerAuthHandler` with that. For more information, please refer: https://ballerina.io/learn/how-to-write-secure-ballerina-code/#implementing-outbound-custom-authentication-mechanism